# Code or setting to hide or change color of gesture bar (also called app switcher) iOS 10+

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need to make the screen go completely black in my app, but I still see the new thin line at the bottom that replaced the physical button in iPhone Xr and Xs.

I have looked at settings and googled like crazy.  I called apple tech support to get the name of the bar itself. They said either 'gesture bar' or 'app switcher bar'. Do you know the code or setting required to change it's color or make it invisible?

N/A

Hoping to black out entire screen, but the thin line bar at the bottom shows up (this is not the tab bar or navigation items, but rather the new bar the user swipes up in the newer phones.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this UIViewController API that hide "Home Indicator".
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887510-prefershomeindicatorautohidden

Override the following method on the ViewController you want to hide the indicator.

```
override var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

- prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden
  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887510-prefershomeindicatorautohidden
- setNeedsUpdateOfHomeIndicatorAutoHidden()
  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887509-setneedsupdateofhomeindicatoraut
- childForHomeIndicatorAutoHidden
  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887508-childforhomeindicatorautohidden

Comment: Thank you so much!  Funny that even the top level Apple support didn't know the 'technical name 'Home Indicator'.  Best regards!